# Can I style MenuItem Caption in Vaadin7

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7

Is there any possibility to customize Vaadin 7 Menuitem so that text is in Left side, NOT in right side and it is aligned evenly  with icon?  Second question is that is it possible to give different style to top level menu than other levels?

Css:

```
.v-menubar .v-icon {
float: right;
```

[image]

```
<div class="v-slot v-slot-user-menu">
  <div id="menu.ui.UserView.user-chooser" class="v-menubar v-widget user-menu v-menubar-user-menu" tabindex="0">
    <span class="v-menubar-menuitem">
        <span class="v-menubar-submenu-indicator">►</span>
        <span class="v-menubar-menuitem-caption">
            <span class="v-icon FontAwesome"></span>
            Adam Test
            </span>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to force it:

```
.v-menubar .v-icon {
text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: It is not working. There is another problem as well. If I style the toplevel, my submenus will go broken.

Comment: can you give me a fiddle? it would be way easier to see what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
.v-menubar-menuitem-caption {
//style
}
```

If you want more css look in the vaadin docs at